# ElasticSearch top results vary when max is varied for TopChildrenQueryBuilder query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an index with child and parent documents and I am using the children to query the parents. I get search results but the results are not consistent. The index is static, I am not adding anything during these tests.

I whittled the code down to the basics:

```html
 
int max = 50;
String query = "politics";
SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch("users").setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH);

QueryBuilder b = QueryBuilders.topChildrenQuery( "children", QueryBuilders.termQuery( "name", query ) );
builder.setQuery( b );
builder.setFrom(0).setSize(max);

SearchResponse response = builder.execute().actionGet();

SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
List<Map> users = new ArrayList<Map>();

System.err.printlnt( hits.getTotalHits() );

for( SearchHit hit : hits.getHits() )
{
//do stuff
```

The issue is when I vary max it changes the top results returned. The first few results shift around, but are consistent based on what max I use. As I increase max the top few results seem to increase in relevancy, almost like it wasn't actually searching the full index unless I pressed it. Also, the number of total hits it claims it found varied, it would increase as I increased max. For a max of 10 it said the total hits was 93. For 100 it said 731. For 1000 it said 8040.

Is this a bug with TopChildrenQueryBuilder, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is some sort of feature.

From the docs:

"One downside of using the top_children is that if there are more child docs matching the required hits when executing the child query, then the total_hits result of the search response will be incorrect."

I don't know what that means, but it seems like they didn't have accuracy or relevance in mind when designing this feature.

My fix (for now) is to get much more hits than I need and hope it doesn't slow things down too much.

UPDATE

Apparently you can control this by using the "factor" method. Here is an explanation:

"Controls the multiplication factor of the initial hits required from the child query over the main query request. Defaults to 5."

Not sure what that means exactly but I set it to 1000 and it seems "fixed". The queries aren't very fast, but it is faster than using the hack I mentioned above, and it seems to have the same effect.